# load application context for junit hibernate tests inside spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, applicationcontext

I've got a properly defined spring configuration XML file, which imports some other XML files. THe test should read/write/delete records from MySQL database. I've got a problem with hibernate - the test is unable to access the database and hibernate throws following exception:

```
Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor];
nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException:
Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
```

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = "classpath:*.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class JukeboxTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private Jukebox jukebox;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        jukebox = (Jukebox) applicationContext.getBean("metal_jukebox");
        sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) applicationContext.getBean("sessionFactory");
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println(jukebox.getName());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testGetName() {
        assertEquals("Metal Jukebox", jukebox.getName());
    }
```

This is my hibernate config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.blogspot.symfonyworld.lyricsbase.model.Song</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

the system.out line properly displays value defined in the bean XML, so the configuration is ok. I guess the annotations are somehow wrong, but I don't know what to fix, since the exception tells me nothing.

This is the exception stack trace:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:594)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:495)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:846)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:588)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:297)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:192)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:396)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:91)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getStatisticsImplementor(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1468)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getStatistics(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1464)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterTransaction(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.afterTransactionCompletion(JdbcTransaction.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:488)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: I can see that sessionFactory.close(); inside tearDown is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Please define the bean JukeBox in the test context if this is a service.

If this is dao then please inject the entitymanager, transaction manager and session factory to the bean.